# Will BT 4.2 in Classic Mode connect to BT 2.1+EDR?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, compatibility

I am having a BT **dual mode** EVK which can operate in BT 4.2 LE and **Classic** as well.

I want to check if this module would connect/ be compatible with my BT access point which is of **BT 2.1+EDR**.

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy (AKA Bluetooth LE, BLE, BT 4.X, 5.X) is not back-compatible with any Bluetooth classic (Bluetooth 1.x, 2.x, 3.x). So, you will *not* be able to connect a BLE module to BT 2.1. The kit you describe has 2 stacks in parallel, so you should be able to connect the kit to the access point, but only via BT Classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming that you are after a normal connection then you dual mode Bluetooth 4.2 device should connect to a BT2.1 +EDR device. Most Android phones nowadays support dual mode Bluetooth 4.X (where X is 0, 1, or 2) and they can connect to BT 2.1 +EDR devices without an issue.

Comment: Thanks Youssif, it's clear now. Is it the same with BT 5? Will BT 5 also connect to BT 2.1 + EDR directly?